# How to deploy Rails 5 with Ruby 2.5 in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ruby-on-rails-5

I followed instruction from Goolgle [Running Rails 5 on the Google App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine)
and follow error report about google-protobuf which [not work with Ruby 2.5.](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/4098)
But some report cleanly work! 
I tried by installed the working version for Ruby 2.5

```
$ gem install google-protobuf -v '3.5.1.1'
```

still showed error below when bundle to install gem 'google-cloud'

> Using google-api-client 0.14.5
>   Using google-cloud-env 1.0.2
>   Using google-cloud-core 1.2.2
>   Using google-cloud-bigquery 0.29.0
>   Fetching google-protobuf 3.2.0.2 (universal-darwin)
>   Installing google-protobuf 3.2.0.2 (universal-darwin)
>   Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: google-protobuf requires Ruby
>   version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.
>   An error occurred while installing google-protobuf
>   (3.2.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install google-protobuf -v '3.2.0.2'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   google-cloud was resolved to 0.44.0, which depends on
>   google-cloud-datastore was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
>         google-gax was resolved to 0.8.12, which depends on googleapis-common-protos was resolved to 1.3.7, which depends on
>             grpc was resolved to 1.6.7, which depends on googleapis-common-protos-types was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
>                 google-protobuf

Comment: Could you solve your issue? I've been able to run the example tutorial successfully with Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 5.2.0 and Cloud SDK 210.0.0. What versions of those have you installed? Have you installed another library that led to this error?

Comment: No not yet. I skipped example and tried to run my existing app. If you can, I should start from tutorial. Thanks that all I need. And I have so many gems including my own. Which sample you tried, need to check the google-protobuf issues!